# Cant realtime update recycleView whith realm

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

Sorry for my english. I have list objects, it list contains switch btn. When user change some switch i neeed it update in db. I 
But when i try change swith, i have error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction.
```

I can not understand how create adapter, who can update realtime data

My **adapter**:

```
   public class DocumentTypeAdapterDB extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<DocType, DocumentTypeAdapterDB.ViewHolder> {

    RealmList<DocType> docTypes;

    public DocumentTypeAdapterDB(@Nullable RealmList<DocType> docTypes, Context context) {
        super(docTypes, true);
        this.docTypes = docTypes;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_doc_type, null);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        ViewHolder rcv = new ViewHolder(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final DocType docType = docTypes.get(position);

        holder.switch_item.setText(docType.name);



        //check box
        holder.switch_item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!holder.switch_item.isChecked()) {
                    docType.is_check = false;
                } else {
                    docType.is_check = true;
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return docTypes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        SwitchCompat switch_item;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            switch_item = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_item);
        }

        public void clearAnimation()
        { itemView.clearAnimation(); }
    }


}
```

**DocType**

```
public class DocType extends RealmObject{
public boolean is_check;
    public String name;
    //getter and setter

}
```

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the recyclerview first so that the layout would be refresh the code for that is invalidate(). And suggestions there are lots of realtime databases in the market now example is firebase you have to check that out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need transaction to modify `RealmObject`s.

So, you should get `Realm` instance that `docTypes` belongs to and then:

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        docType.is_check = holder.switch_item.isChecked();
    }
});
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks wary much! You make my day)

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved me